# Re-auto-fit MKAnnotationView's callout into map view

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a map with an annotation on it that has a callout. That annotation moves and at some point the callout will get out of the screen, if opened while moving.

The only way I could find to fix this is to call `deselectAnnotation:` and then `selectAnnotation:` on the map view.

The only problem I have with this is that you have to call `selectAnnotation:` with the animated parameter set to `YES` in order to refit the callout, which makes the callout bounce-open at every move.

Is there a more elegant way to autofit the callout, except re-inventing the wheel by creating your own custom callout?

Thank you!